# React window.Calendly undefined

Tags: reactjs, calendly

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // I've initiated Calendly in this effect
  }, [])

  console.log(window.Calendly)
```

I got undefined when I print window.Calendly, but when I print just window, I got an object contains Calendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effects run *after* rendering. So you're logging first, and then setting up `window.Calendly` later.

When you switch to logging `window`, you're now logging an object. The developer tools do not evaluate what's in that object until you click to inspect it. So by the time you click, `window.Calendly` exists, but it didn't exist when the log statement ran.

Comment: ahaa thank you @nicholas, so how i can append the script before first render so i can access it from window.Calendly.

Comment: If you want to append the script before this component renders, then you'll need to put the appending logic in some parent component, and have the parent component only render this component once the appending is complete.